# Trouble understanding the code for CS50 Week 4: Recover

Tags: c, cs50

So while I understood most of the code for recover....I'm having trouble understanding certain parts of it. I have written a summary of what I think is happening in the code and would appreciate it if someone could correct me if my explanation is wrong in anyway.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Check how many input commands
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Invalid Usage. Try ./recover IMAGE\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Open file and make sure input file is valid
    FILE* input_file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (input_file == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not open file.\n");
        return 2;
    }

    // Buffer to read through each block of memory
    uint8_t buffer[512] = {0};

    // Count number of images
    int count_image = 0;

    // Creating output file
    FILE* output_file = NULL;

    // Allocating space for output file name
    char* filename = malloc(sizeof(char));

    // Reading through the input file
    while (fread(buffer, sizeof(uint8_t), 512, input_file))
    {
        // Checking for JPEG header
        if ((buffer[0] == 0xff) && (buffer[1] == 0xd8) && (buffer[2] == 0xff) && ((buffer[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0))
        {

            // Write JPEG filename
            sprintf(filename, "%03i.jpg", count_image);

            // Open output file
            output_file = fopen(filename, "w");

            // Increment image
            count_image++;

        }

        // If file hasn't been been used yet
        if (output_file != NULL)
        {
            fwrite(buffer, sizeof(uint8_t), 512, output_file);
        }

    }

    free(filename);
    fclose(output_file);
    fclose(input_file);

    return 0;
}
```

So in this problem we are supposed to recover JPEG's. The memory card has a bunch of **512 byte size blocks**. JPEGs can use multiple of these 512 size blocks and any excess space is filled with 0s.

We start of by doing the standard stuff of making sure that the inputs are valid and that the input file opens without any error. Then we initialize a buffer to store 512 byte size blocks, so that we can iterate through the memory card one block at a time. Then we initialize **count-image** to count images, and an empty pointer called **output-file**. Finally we initialize another pointer called **filename**, to make space for storing the file name of the output-file.

Now we open the while loop. Here I've used uint8_t, so that means we will be iterating through each byte in the 512 byte block, until the file ends. If we reach the end of the file and a byte can no longer be read, fread will return 0 and the while loop will exit. So now we have **buffer**, which is an array of size 512, consisting of 512 8-bit elements.

Now we check if the first, second, third, and fourth elements of the buffer, match the sequence of a JPEG header or not. If it does, we use **sprintf** to store the name of that file in in the memory pointed to by filename.

Since we have started reading a JPEG, we now assign the empty pointer, output-file, to a new file that we open with the string that is stored in filename. My question here is...**does fopen create the new file**?

Then we increment the counter. This way we print images from 0 to 49 as opposed to 0 to 50 if we were to count images before sprintf.

Then since we assigned the pointer already, it is no longer null, and we go into the next if statement and write whatever is stored in the buffer into the output file.

Now we check for the next 512 byte block. If it doesn't start with a JPEG header, then we continue writing it into the same output file, as it means its the continuation of the first image.

When we find the 2nd JPEG header, sprintf stores "1" at the address filename is pointing at. Then we open a **NEW file** in write mode, with the new filename ("1"). Then after incrementing the counter, we now start writing into the new file instead as the pointer is pointing to the new file now.

Then we repeat the same process until the end of the file to create 50 files consisting of a JPEG image each, named from 0.jpg to 49.jpg. (Its mentioned in the problem that there are 50 images in total)

Running this code seems to produce a **memory leak**....is it because I'm not closing each individual output file before opening the next?

Comment: A number of problems here. At first glance, you're only allocating a single byte for the `filename` buffer then writing 8 characters there via `sprintf()`. UB.

Comment: Yea the errors got fixed as soon as i used 8*sizeof(char). What exactly do you mean when you say that im writing 8 characters into the memory block? Is "%03i.jpg" at least 8 bytes long?

Answer (score 3):

1. Yes, `fopen(filename,"w")` creates `filename` if it doesn't exist and truncates it to 0 bytes if it does (see [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html)).
2. You are right. Not closing `output_file` before opening a new file is a bug and causes a memory leak.
3. This line is wrong: `char* filename = malloc(sizeof(char));`. It allocates one byte only, but you need at least 8 bytes including `'\0'` (assuming you find at most 999 images)

Comment: Yea the errors got fixed as soon as i used 8*sizeof(char). What exactly do you mean when you say that im writing 8 characters into the memory block? Is "%03i.jpg" at least 8 bytes long?

Comment: The filename produced by `sprintf(...)` is at least 7 bytes long (nnn.jpg) and you need an extra byte for the trailing `'\0'` - making 8. But if `count_image` became 1000, you'd create "1000.jpg" and needed 9 bytes for the filename.

Comment: Oh i see....thanks a lot for all of this info

Comment: Yes, given the format string ‘%03i.jpg’ at least 8 characters (7 + NUL) will be written to the memory location at `buffer` (more if `count_image` exceeds 999). Note `sizeof(char)` is defined as 1 so `8*sizeof(char)` will always be 8. The multiplication doesn’t hurt but it’s not necessary.